# running python setup.py test pip not finding pip.conf to install internal requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-14.04, setup.py

can't find anyone posting a similar situation so thought I'd ask and see.  Currently trying to automate unit tests within our continuous deployment environment.

We do the typical python setup.py test command from our virtualenv. However, we have our own internal pypi server for some of our internal libraries.  pip.conf is configured so when explicitly running pip install it will check the internal pypi server.  But when running setup.py test, it tries to use pip to install requirements and appears to not be aware of the pip.conf file.  I've place the pip.conf at the global level (/etc/pip.config), virtualenv level, and the user level but to no avail.  It's almost like it's calling a different pip, which I would assume would be the base install (not virtualenv), but it ignores the global pip.conf also.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Any time I have problems like this, I find that writing the explicit path to the executable helps a great deal, no matter the level I place the executable. So instead of running `pip ~do something~` try `/etc/pip ~do something~`.

Comment: Unfortunately setup.py is calling pip and I'm not sure of a way to have it explicitly run the one I want.  I assumed that using python from a virtualenv would've picked the pip from it's environment that appears not to be the case.  Currently my work around is having a requirements.txt file to explicitly install requirements before I run unit tests.  But I don't like having two different files to maintain the same list of requirements.

Comment: I've found that also to be the case, that even though I created my venv with pip3.5, when I called pip it would run pip2.7 (I don't know why this happens exactly..). Again, I solved this my laying the path to the correct pip3.5 in my venv. `/usr/local/venvs/env1/bin/pip ~do something~` You can check to see what version of pip is being called with `pip --version' in the terminal--in and outside the venv.